# Как организовать Java код и избежать switch конструкций при передаче объекто

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, рефакторинг, .net

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение на ЯП Java. Для передачи данных использую библиотеку KryoNet. суть вопроса - когда передаю некоторые данные (в виде общего Класса) с клиента на сервер или наоборот они обобщаются до типа Object, следовательно на принимающей стороне мне нужно эти данные привести вновь к тому-же типу и использовать Instance со switch'ами не вариант, т.к. таких классов множество, какие паттерны можно использовать для организации кода без switch`ей и условных операторов, или как можно организовать код.

```
public class RegistrationData {
public  enum Code{
    EMAIL_EXIST,
    LOGIN_EXIST,
    SUCCESS;
}

public class Response{
    public Code code;
    public Response(Code code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
public class Request{
    public String login;
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public Request(String login, String email, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

}

Пример одного из таких классов - сервер получает Request должен на его основе ,после запросов из БД, сформировать Response.

```
public void received(Connection c, Object p){
        //Проверяем какой отправляется пакет 
        if(p instanceof PacketMessage){
            //Если мы получили PacketMessage .
            PacketMessage packet = (PacketMessage) p; 
            System.out.println("Ответ от сервера: "+packet.message);
            
            //Мы получили сообщение
            messageReceived = true;
        }
    } 

public class PacketMessage {
    String message;
    }
```

[из статьи](https://www.pvsm.ru/java/45194)

Comment: Да, изначальный. В начале я передаю данные типа Request из клиента в сервер, они приходят на сервер как Object. На сервере мне нужно получить этот объект, как-то перевести его в тип Request (вопрос как без If конструкций), затем обработать в зависимости от данных в нем и отправить клиенту Response; В различных Data классах - Response и Request отличаются полями.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я добавил в вопрос

Comment: hash map же, нет? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `kryonet` можно использовать типизированные обработчики если использовать не `Listener` а `ReflectionListener`.

То есть в том же примере вместо:

```
public class ServerProgram extends Listener {
    ...
}
```

делайте так:

```
public class ServerProgram extends Listener.ReflectionListener {
    ...
}
```

И тогда вместо нетипизированного обработчика создавайте типизированный:

```
public void received(Connection c, PacketMessage packet){
   System.out.println("Ответ от сервера: "+packet.message);
            
   //Мы получили сообщение
   messageReceived = true;
}
```

`ReflectionListener` сам вызовет правильный метод в зависимости от типа объекта, который получен.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это решение мне идеально подходит.

Comment: а не могли бы кинуть ссылку на документацию, где вы об этом узнали, если не затруднит.

Comment: Я глянул в исходный код https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/Listener.java#L58. Там еще есть полезные вещи такие как ThreadedListener.

Comment: спасибо, почитаю.